# How do I inherit in a "second degree" within one table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, single-table-inheritance

I have a class `Resource0` and a class `Resource1` which inherit from a class `ResourceContainer1` which inherits from a class `Resource`.

The model for my class *Resource* looks like this:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :type
end

class ResourceContainer0 < Resource
end

class ResourceContainer1 < Resource
end

class Resource0 < ResourceContainer1
end

class Resource1 < ResourceContainer1
end
```

In migration my class *Resource* looks somethow like this:

```
class CreateResources < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :resources do |t|
      t.string :type #inheritance -> Resource

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
 end
```

I'm wondering if multiple `:type` arguments are required in order to make this work and if that's even possible?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I can't see that you'd need another type column.  Did it work when you tried it?  I'd expect the type to contain the class_name as usual.

Comment: i have tried this and it doesn't run.. i was thinking, that i'd need another :type in ResourceContainer to create an object from Resource0 oder Resource1 (which can't be found)

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine.  Must be something else thats failing.  In console, try Resource1.create and see if it succeeds or fails.  If it fails, check errors on the object.

Comment: ok it does work- i assigned the :type in a wrong way:-( THANKS!